# A Simple Example of Hermitian Products

Tags: linear-algebra

- If $X=(x_1,x_2)=(1,i)$ then

$$X.X=1-1=0.$$

I think that $$X.X=x_1x^{-}_1+x_2x^{-}_2=1.1+i(-i)=1+(-i^2)=1+1=2.$$

Note: $x^{-}_1,x^{-}_2$ means transpose of $x_1,x_2$, respectively.

**Can you say that where is the a typo in my statement?**

Comment: The first computation didn't conjugate.

Comment: @cmk conjugate of $i$ is $-i$, right?

Comment: Yup, you got it.